# Equation of Plane involving Intersection of planes

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

Find a plane through $A$ $(2, 1, -1)$ and perpendicular to the line of
intersection of the planes $2x + y - z = 3$ and $x + 2y + z = 2$. Not too sure of what to do here, I know I need to find the point of intersection of the planes, and I found two points that I think are on the line of intersection, $B$ ($5/3$ ,$0$ ,$1/3$) and $C$ ($4/3$, $1/3$, $0$ ). However, I don't know where to go from there, and with the plane needing to be perpendicular. 
Answer given is $x$-$y$+$z$=$0$ Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the two planes equations gives

$$x+y=\frac 53$$

thus $$y=\frac 53-x$$

and

$$z=2-x-2y=2-\frac{10}{3}+x$$

the line intersection of the two planes has parametric equations :

$$x=0+x$$
$$y=\frac 53-x$$
$$z=\frac{-4}{3}+x$$

the vector director of this line is
$$(1,-1,1)$$

the plane perpendicular to this line has the equation
$$x-y+z=d$$
it contains the point $(2,1,-1)$ if $$d=0$$

the equation you are looking for is
$$\boxed{x-y+z=0}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

A directing vector of the intersection line of the two planes is the cross-product $u=\vec n_1\times \vec n_2$ of the normal vectors of the planes.

Once you calculated its coordinates, the equation of the plane you're after is, in vector form
$$\vec u\cdot \overrightarrow{OM}=\vec u\cdot \overrightarrow{OA}.$$